# Is there a way to continuously receive updated mongodb data sent from main.js to renderer.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

I am creating a desktop app with electron alongside mongodb as my data store. I am sending data retrieved from mongodb (in main process) to the renderer process. My goal is to receive updated data from mongodb every time the data changes. Is there a way to automatically and continuously get the updated data and then change the table data in html (renderer side).

I've tried to set an interval that will get the data every 10 seconds, (inspired by how ajax works) but it failed. 
I've also tried to implement an event listener for data change in mongodb from main process that will emit a signal and then sends new data and update it, but it got too complicated and confusing and also failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changeStreams for this purpose:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

If you're using mongoose as an ORM, you can just call `.watch()` on your model and define a function to run on the change event

```
YourModel.watch().on('change', data => console.log(new Date(), data));
```

In that function, you can do something to update the client, using something like push notifications, graphql subscriptions or websocket messages